# multiple jquery popups in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

am showing a list of emails, and for each email on click, am trying to create a popup, to show the full email content....

the prob is that, popup works only for 1st email, for rest it doent show anything,

here is my code,

```
foreach ($email as $x){

            echo "<div id='popuup_div' class='popup_msg'>";
            echo "<div id='image'>";
            echo $html->image('mail.png');
            echo "</div>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo $client['Email']['body'];
            echo "</div>";

            $show = substr($client['Email']['body'], 0, 65);


            echo $html->tableCells(array(array($client['Email']['date'], $client['Email']['time'],
                            $client['Email']['from'], $show . "......" .
                            "<div id='popupShow'> Show more....... </div>")));}
```

jquery code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
 `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

jQuery('#popupShow').click(function(e){
  //getting height and width of the message box
  var height = jQuery('#popuup_div').height();
  var width = jQuery('#popuup_div').width();
  //calculating offset for displaying popup message
  leftVal=e.pageX-(width/1.5)+"px";
  topVal=e.pageY-(height/13)+"px";
  //show the popup message and hide with fading effect
  jQuery('#popuup_div').css({left:leftVal,top:topVal}).show();
});

jQuery('#image').click(function(e)
{
jQuery('#popuup_div').fadeOut('fast');
});
});`

how can i make it works for all the emails?

Answer (score 2):

HTML id's must be unique. Try replacing your id's with classes.

Comment: I agree. In addition to this, you can place all your dialogs into a container div with an id like "my-dialogs".  When you need to create a dialog, do: `jQuery('.some-dialog-class', '#my-dialogs').dialog();`  This optimization will make it faster to locate the dialog HTML.  Also keeps the HTML a little neater :)

Comment: i tried replacing with classes, now the popup works for all the emails. but the popup content is the same for all and it is the last email content......

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a lot of CakePHP in this problem. Nor do I see a loop that would iterate over the emails.